# How to use initating user to run a Workflow (and not the system account) in SP 2007

Tags: 2007, workflow, infopath

The problem I'm having is trying to update the approval status of an item in a document library. The error I get is: "Error updating a list item". This is if I have the item checked out first using the workflow. If I don't check it out first, I get the "Item is checked out" error instead. Some people have said that workflows shouldn't run on the system account, so does anyone know how to specify that it does NOT run on the system account?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Sharepoint environment is running Service Pack 2, workflows are already running under the the context of the initiator and not the system account.

Comment: We're upgraded past service pack 2, but every one of my workflows runs under System Account.  Thanks.